# Error: lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-ref

I am new to typescript.

I have the custom react hook written with typescript. The hook checks if a `div` element has overflowing content:

`useOverflowY.ts`

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

function useOverflowY(() => {
  const [isOverflowY, setIsOverflowY] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { current } = ref;

    if (current) {
      const hasOverflowY = current.scrollHeight > window.innerHeight;
      setIsOverflowY(hasOverflowY);
    }
  }, [ref]);

  return {ref, isOverflowY};
}

export default useOverflowY;
```

I am getting this error which I am not sure of how to fix:

```
'useOverflowY', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.ts(7010)
```

Not sure what exactly this error means and how I should fix it.

Comment: Probably you missed this

`function useOverflowY(() => { `

instead of 

`function useOverflowY{`

Comment: Your current code is not valid JS/TS syntax. Did you mean `function useOverflowY() {...}` *or* `const useOverflowY = () => {...}`  instead of `function useOverflowY(() => {...}`. More importantly, once this syntax error is fixed, do you still get the error?

Comment: Oh yes, that is right! That is what I meant to write. Thank you! Had to just write `function useOverflowY() {...}`

Comment: Would you be able to [upload your project](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) to codesandbox.io (or similar) so we could get more context? Normally types are inferred in cases like this and you shouldn't be seeing this warning. My guess is you might have other minor syntax typos, like the one mentioned above.

Comment: This is my first time using CodeSandbox. Hope it works. Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sharp-pond-394o6f?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A41%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A41%7D%5D